# Outlook 2013 Missing Emails in Inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've just swapped machines from Windows 7 with Office 2010 to Windows 8.1 with Office 2013.

I ran Outlook (for the first time) and used the start-up wizard to connect to my email account (this always works fine on other email addresses on the same domain) and everything worked fine, however my inbox folder is showing as empty.

I looked online and found a lot of topics suggesting I select root directory of the email but after going to Internet Email Settings > Advanced, I don't have an option in this dialog box to enter the root folder.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How long have you given it? Is this a POP3 account, IMAP, Exchange? I have this issue with IMAP, the only answer I found was to wait longer (yes, seriously). IMAP is complicated as MS require a flag to be set (Can't find a source at the moment) which not all mail servers do. Who are you hosting your email with (Gmail/Hotmail/Some other)?

Comment: It's an Exchange account. Managed on our behalf by a third party supplier. It may not be relevant, but the SPAM filter is awful. It filter legitimate important emails.

Comment: If that is the case, I think you need to ask them direct since they could have something set up which we can't know of...

Comment: I guess what I'm unsure of is the fact that I've done this before on multiple machines and never had a problem. Thanks for your answer, I'll try and contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments, it could be the 3rd party provider.

To test it, simply add an account (one that works on another machine) to the faulty machine. If that works, then you know the issue is most likely with the account.

Try the faulty account on another computer. If it works, then it's likely the computer/Outlook settings.

You also stated you used the wizard, it may be worth trying it manually.

Comment: Many thanks. Contacted the supplier and it turned out to be something on their end. Now resolved. Many thanks.